# Make a list inside another list in a gerrit comment

Tags: gerrit

In a gerrit comment, I make a [list of bullet points](https://wiki.hpdd.intel.com/display/PUB/2012/02/16/Comment+formatting+on+Gerrit) with the * (star)

```
* item A
* item B
```

How to go about having two levels of bullet points?

```
* item A
    - subitem A_1
    - subitem A_2
* item B
```

Comment: I hope there is an answer for this question. I've always found  gerrit markdown to be an underwhelming mystery.

Answer (score 0):

it just have some basic formatting as far as I know. It seems there is not any second level list bullet.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/S58dBK1nQBw